# Scroll eventlistener not working in React js

Tags: reactjs

```
In my website project in React js, the scroll event not working
In app.js, I put the below code

  useEffect(() => {
    const toggleVisibility = () => {
      if (window.scrollY > 500) {
        console.log('yes');
      } else {
        console.log('no');
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", toggleVisibility);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", toggleVisibility);
  },[])
```

toggleVisibility function not trigered, So I created new react project and i tried this code in new react project, it works fine. What could be the reason that not worked the scroll event in the specific project.

Comment: You'd better provide more information about your question. By gathering this detailed information, others can have a better understanding of the problem's context and provide more accurate answers or suggestions.
You can check here [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.